# Getting Values from Bootstrap Select without knowing the id of the select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#noIdea').append($('<option>').val("ddd").text("Value 4"))
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
  let newval = "ddd";
  let oldval = [];
  oldval.push($('input[type="text"].mySelect').val());
  //oldval = ($('#noIdea').val());
  oldval.push(newval);
  console.log (oldval)
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', oldval);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.12/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.12/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<select multiple id="noIdea" class="selectpicker mySelect" data-live-search="true">
<option value="aaa" selected>Value 1</option>
<option value="bbb" selected>Value 2</option>
<option value="ccc">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

I have a Bootstrap Select where I need to get the values that where chosen before and add another (new) value as selected that is pushed from outside. Problem is: I do not know the `#id` of this select as it is randomly generated, only its `.class`. But the class is unique as I only have one `.mySelect` on this page.

So what I do is:

```
let oldval = [];
oldval.push($('input[type="text"].mySelect').val()); //<- That is empty
oldval.push(newValueIreceived);
$('.mySelect').selectpicker('refresh');
$('.mySelect').selectpicker('val', oldval);
```

using `oldval.push($('#id').val());` it would work. Can anybody tell me why I do not get the value when using the class?

Comment: Why not `oldval.push($('.mySelect').val());`?

Comment: Doesn't work either. I already tried that.

Comment: Please update the the question with minimum executable code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the class as the selector, you may receive the list in return. You need to loop on the list and push the values.

Try this:

```
let oldval = [];
$('input[type="text"].mySelect').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val()){
        oldval.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Please note, if you could share your HTML as well, we will be able to debug/test it properly.

Comment: That nearly did it. Thanks! Only that `$(this).val()` gives back an Array already. So with changing it to `oldval = ($(this).val());`the Code works.

Comment: this works if you only have a single select on the page because only the last found select would be available in the oldval. however, for a more universal solution, I would use the original code by Mayank Patel, where oldval would be an array of arrays, which tells you how many selects were processed and you can iterate over the values of each one as you choose